# TFS Eclipse for Selenium (Shelving changes or labeling)

Tags: eclipse, selenium, tfs, label, shelve

We are working on doing selenium automation and use Eclipse with TFS plug-in.
We have two teams
Automation team which creates the test on the devlopment build and Functional team which runs the test on the released build.

So for example I have files for testing one of the screen 
(Detail_GWAPI.java , Details.java , FrameworkFunction.java, SQLScriptGeneral.java)
I have done my dry runs, reviews and approval and have checked in the changes to TFS. 
We have multiple files for various screens/ functionalities.

Now the function testing team gets a released build and they start the execution. They get the latest and execute the tests based on the instructions.

In the meantime my automation team is working on new features to automate and are adding/creating more testing scripts and at times also updating the existing files and check-in the changes to TFS.

How can I have the automation team still save these changes to TFS but when the functional test team gets the latest they should not get those changes as they are not there on the build which they are running the test.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible. Since you have mentioned these changes have saved to TFS. The latest version of this are in the source control. So when the functional test team gets 'the latest', they will have to get the new changes. Unless they select to get a specific changeset.

For your situation, the best way to create a new branch. One branch are for the test automation team and one branch are for the functional team. One for release branch. Automation team can check in all the new changes in their branch and until all changes tests passed then merge them to the release branch. The Functional team can get the latest version of release branch to run the test..

Moreover, there is the function of [Shelve and Unshelve Pending Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475918(v=vs.100).aspx) are also supported in Team Explorer Everywhere, details can refer the link from MSDN.